# How can I clip a drawn canvas, rotate and draw to another canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine, viewport

I have a canvas for the game world and a canvas for the display screen. I also have a polygon with nodes V(x,y) to serve as a viewport that follows the player and his rotation. I would like to know how to clip from the game world along the polygon, rotate and draw to the smaller canvas.[image]`

```
//main looping function
var requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

//joystick setup
var leftManager = null;
var rightManager = null;

//precalculated math
var twoPi = Math.PI*2;
var halfPi = Math.PI/2;
var thirdOfCircleInRadians = twoPi/3;


//game canvas setup
var gameCvs = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
gameCvs.width = 480;
gameCvs.height = 320;
//gameCvs.width - 960;
//gameCvs.height = 640;
var gameCtx = gameCvs.getContext("2d");

//game loop
var lastTime = 0;
function main() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = lastTime==0? 0.016 : (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;
    update(dt);
    render(dt);
    lastTime = now;
    requestAnimFrame(main);
}

//collision class shorthand
var V = SAT.Vector;
var C = SAT.Circle;
var P = SAT.Polygon;
var R = new SAT.Response();

P.prototype.draw = function (ctx,type) {

    ctx.save();
    switch(type){
        case 'van': ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.5)"; break;
        case 'col': ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)"; break;
        default: ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)"; break;
    }
    ctx.translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    var points = this.calcPoints;
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    var i = points.length;
    while (i--) ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    ctx.closePath();
    //stroke to see through camera, when camera is not drawn use fill
    ctx.stroke();
    //ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
};

//first for collisions, second for vanity. first is black, second is grey
var O = function(colPolygon,vanPolygon){
    this.colPolygon = colPolygon;
    this.vanPolygon = vanPolygon;
    this.visible = false;
};


var objectVendor = function(type,position){
    switch(type){
        case 'tree': 
        return new O(new P(position,[
            new V(10.5,19.5),
            new V(20.5,9.5),
            new V(23,-4),
            new V(15,-16.5),
            new V(-4,-19.5),
            new V(-18,-14.5),
            new V(-23,-0.5),
            new V(-18.5,14.5),
            new V(-8,20)
            ]),new P(position,[
            new V(21,39),
            new V(41,19),
            new V(46,-8),
            new V(30,-33),
            new V(-8,-39),
            new V(-36,-29),
            new V(-46,-1),
            new V(-37,29),
            new V(-16,40)]));
        break;
        default: return false; break;
    }
    return false;
}

//Camera and Player Polygons

var cameraPoly = new P(new V(0,0),[
        new V(-240,-160),
        new V(240,-160),
        new V(240,160),
        new V(-240,160)
    ]);


var player = new P(new V(0,0),[
        new V(5,2.5),
        new V(7.5,2),
        new V(7.5,-2),
        new V(5,-2.5),
        new V(-5,-2.5),
        new V(-7.5,-2),
        new V(-7.5,2),
        new V(-5,2.5)
    ]);
//players start position on the screen, and starting angle, init velocity
player.pos = new V(240,160);
player.setAngle(1);
//players velocity for movement
player.vel = new V(0,0);

var world = {
    objects: [],
    visibleObjects: [],
    worldCvs: null,
    worldCtx: null,
    init: function(){
        //set up world canvas
        this.worldCvs = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.worldCvs.width = 480;
        this.worldCvs.height = 480;
        this.worldCtx = this.worldCvs.getContext("2d");
        //populate world with stuff
        this.objects.push(objectVendor('tree',new V(100,100)));
        this.objects.push(objectVendor('tree',new V(150,200)));
        this.objects.push(objectVendor('tree',new V(75,300)));
    },
    update: function(dt){
            this.visibleObjects = [];

            cameraPoly.setAngle(player.angle);
            //cameraPoly.pos = player.pos;
            cameraPoly.pos = new V(player.pos.x+(110*Math.cos(player.angle+halfPi)),player.pos.y+(110*Math.sin(player.angle+halfPi)));
            //update objects to mark if they are in view
            var i = this.objects.length;
            while(i--){
                if(SAT.testPolygonPolygon(this.objects[i].vanPolygon, cameraPoly, R)){
                    this.visibleObjects.push(this.objects[i]);
                }
            }
        //}
    },
    draw: function(dt){

        this.worldCtx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        this.worldCtx.clearRect(0,0,this.worldCvs.width,this.worldCvs.height);
        player.draw(this.worldCtx);
        var i = this.visibleObjects.length;
        while(i--){
            this.visibleObjects[i].colPolygon.draw(this.worldCtx,'col');
            this.visibleObjects[i].vanPolygon.draw(this.worldCtx,'van');
        }
        //for testing
        cameraPoly.draw(this.worldCtx);
        /*
        this.worldCtx.save();
        this.worldCtx.beginPath();
        var i = cameraPoly.calcPoints.length;
        this.worldCtx.moveTo(cameraPoly.calcPoints[0].x,cameraPoly.calcPoints[0].y);
        while(i--){
            this.worldCtx.lineTo(cameraPoly.calcPoints[i].x,cameraPoly.calcPoints[i].y);
        }
        this.worldCtx.clip();
        this.worldCtx.restore();
        */
    }

}

function render(dt){
    gameCtx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    gameCtx.clearRect(0,0,gameCvs.width,gameCvs.height);

    world.draw();
    //gameCtx.save();
    //gameCtx.translate(cameraPoly.pos.x,cameraPoly.pos.y);
    //gameCtx.translate(gameCtx.width/2,gameCtx.height/2);
    //gameCtx.rotate(-player.angle+halfPi);
    //gameCtx.translate(-world.worldCvs.width/2,-world.worldCvs.height/2);

    gameCtx.drawImage(world.worldCvs,0,0);
    //gameCtx.restore();
}

function update(dt){
    world.update();
}

function init(){

    //joystick setup
    leftManager = nipplejs.create({
        zone:document.getElementById("leftJoystick"),
        color:"black",
        size:75,
        threshold:1.0,
        position:{
            top:"50%",
            left:"50%"
        },
        mode:"static",
        restOpacity:0.75,
    });
    rightManager = nipplejs.create({
        zone:document.getElementById("rightJoystick"),
        color:"black",
        size:75,
        threshold:1.0,
        position:{
            top:"50%",
            right:"50%"
        },
        mode:"static",
        restOpacity:0.75,
    });

    //joystick event setup
    leftManager.get().on('move end', function(evt,data){
        //console.log(evt);
        //console.log(data);
    });
    rightManager.get().on('move end', function(evt,data){
        //console.log(evt);
        //console.log(data);
    });
    world.init();
    main();
}
init();
```

`
I'm using libraries SAT.js and nipplejs.js currently.

Comment: By adding 'gameCtx.translate(-cameraPoly.pos.x,-cameraPoly.pos.y);' right before the gameCtx.drawImage call the view follows the correct position, however implementing the rotation is still problematic.

Comment: I've noticed that angleToRotate=-player.angle+Math.PI however applying any type of rotate causes everything to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the render function to the following will solve the problem, just rushing myself and didn't think things through very well. 
`

```
function render(dt){
    gameCtx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    gameCtx.clearRect(0,0,gameCvs.width,gameCvs.height);
    world.draw();
    gameCtx.translate(gameCvs.width/2,gameCvs.height/2);
    gameCtx.rotate(-player.angle+Math.PI);
    gameCtx.translate(-cameraPoly.pos.x,-cameraPoly.pos.y);
    gameCtx.drawImage(world.worldCvs,0,0);
}`
```

What this is doing is resetting any transformations on the context, clearing it for a new redrawing, creating the world canvas, translating to display center, rotating by the proper amount for reference point, translating to reference center point on negative axis to move game canvas proper amount so that drawing at 0,0 is in the correct location. Thank you for the reference material!

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done in a little different of a way than you seem to be thinking of it. Instead of thinking about the viewport existing somewhere in the world, you should think about the viewport being fixed and the world being transformed behind it; you don't copy part of the world to the viewport, you draw the world offset and rotated by a certain amount, and only draw the parts that are inside the viewport. Matrices are an easy and common way to represent this transformation. You may want to [read more about them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

In practice, this would just amount to changing your existing call to `worldCtx.setTransform()` at the beginning of each draw frame. That link has information about how to calculate a good transform matrix, and you can find similar resources all over the place since it's pretty standard math.

In particular, you'll want to multiply a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation) and a translation matrix. Translation matrices are only possible if you use a matrix with higher-order than your coordinate space; for 2D, a 3x3 matrix, and for 3D, a 4x4 matrix. You could instead choose to just add some offset to your coordinates as you draw them, but `worldCtx.setTransform` already takes a matrix with a 3rd column for putting flat offsets into.

Comment: the drawn viewport polygon is used for determining what in the world to render on the game canvas. after the game canvas has been updated/drawn i want to rotate it and draw it on a smaller canvas to align to the viewport polygons dimensions, as they will be fixed in size and equal to each other. i've had trouble with the transformations so far and i'm not sure why. I thought that with the cameras center position and the direction/angle of my player i should be able to translate and rotate the canvas and be able to draw it to the smaller canvas without issue however this is not correct.